# Multi-threaded web scraping in Python/PySide/PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyside

I'm building a web scraper of a kind. Basically, what the soft would do is:

1. User (me) inputs some data (IDs) - IDs are complex, so not just numbers
2. Based on those IDs, the script visits http://localhost/ID

What is the best way to accomplish this? So I'm looking upwards of 20-30 concurrent connections to do it.

I was thinking, would a simple loop be the solution? This loop would start QThreads (it's a Qt app), so they would run concurrently.

The problem I am seeing with the loop however is how to instruct it to use only those IDs not used before i.e. in the iteration/thread that had been executed just before it was? Would I need some sort of a "delegator" function which will keep track of what IDs had been used and delegate the unused ones to the QThreads?

Now I've written some code but I am not sure if it is correct:

```
class GUI(QObject):

   def __init__(self):
        print "GUI CLASS INITIALIZED!!!"
        self.worker = Worker()

        for i in xrange(300):
            QThreadPool().globalInstance().start(self.worker)

class Worker(QRunnable):

    def run(self):
        print "Hello world from thread", QThread.currentThread()
```

Now I'm not sure if these achieve really what I want. Is this actually running in separate threads? I'm asking because `currentThread()` is the same every time this is executed, so it doesn't look that way.

Basically, my question comes down to how do I execute several same QThreads concurrently?

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: You should probably separate the logic from the GUI and only use QT for GUI. The crawler logic should be written in pure python or reuse an existing crawler like [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

Answer (score 5):

As Dikei says, Qt is red herring here. Focus on just using Python threads as it will keep your code much simpler.

In the code below we have a set, `job_queue`, containing the jobs to be executed. We also have a function, `worker_thread` which takes a job from the passed in queue and executes. Here it just sleeps for a random period of time. The key thing here is that `set.pop` is thread safe.

We create an array of thread objects, `workers`, and call `start` on each as we create it. From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) threading.Thread.start runs the given callable in a separate thread of control. Lastly we go through each worker thread and block until it has exited.

```
import threading
import random
import time

pool_size = 5

job_queue = set(range(100))

def worker_thread(queue):
   while True:
        try:
            job = queue.pop()
        except KeyError:
            break

        print "Processing %i..." % (job, )
        time.sleep(random.random())

    print "Thread exiting."

workers = []
for thread in range(pool_size):
    workers.append(threading.Thread(target=worker_thread, args=(job_queue, )))
    workers[-1].start()

for worker in workers:
    worker.join()

print "All threads exited"
```

Comment: It depends actually. If the threads need to communicate with the GUI, `QThread`s will be better and simpler.

Comment: Like @Avaris said, the thread needs to communicate with the GUI thread, and the existing code is largely written as QThread - so I need to use it instead of the Python's built-in threading module. I +1'd you anyway, for the detailed response.

Comment: what is benefit of using time.sleep(random.random())

Comment: It helps to make the example more realistic, each thread won't necessarily take the same amount of time to do their work.